# Get a list filtered by another using ofy()

Tags: java, filter, objectify

My classes:

```
@Entity
@Cache
@Index 
public class Log {
    @Id Long id;    
    Ref<Site> site;     
    Ref<User> user;     
    Ref<Computer> computer;     
    Ref<License> license;   
    private String date_in;     
    private String date_out;    
    private boolean active;
}

@Entity
@Cache
@Index
public class License {
    @Id Long id;
    private String name;
    private String startDate;
    private String expDate;
    private int timeStamp;
    private int status;
    private int offline;
    private String identification;
    Ref<Daemon> daemon;
    private boolean active;
    public enum Type {Country, Site, User, Computer, Lic};
}
```

I don't get why this is not working:

```
ofy().load().type(Log.class)
     .filter("license in",
             ofy().load().type(License.class).filter("name",licName))
     .list();
```

or this too:

```
ofy().load().type(Log.class)
     .filter("license in",
             ofy().load().type(License.class).filter("name",licName).list())
     .list();
```

My License is a reference in my Log. Can I do it using ofy() ?

Can anyone explain me?

Comment: Are Log.license and License.name indexed properties?
It'd be great if you can post the necessary data model (class definition).

Comment: This is impossible to answer without the definitions of Log and License.

Comment: I edited my post with the classes params. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Old question - but it came up in my google search for something else for people looking you need to put `@Index` on the individual properties you want to search on.